# None of the known overfitting prevention techniques works for me, according to learning curves

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, overfitting

I am working on [HTRU2](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/HTRU2) dataset to evaluate classification models. Even though I obtain good results in terms of accuracy-MSE:

[image]

I have an overfitting problem according to the learning curves below. In some of my models (Extra Tree, BaggingClassifier, AdaBoost, Random Forest, Decision Tree, k-NN), the red training curve never goes down as you can see:

[image]

The ways that I have tried to prevent overfitting:

- I was using 30% of the whole dataset for the test set. I have decreased it to 20%, therefore I got a bigger training set but it has no effect on the curves (only slightly in the accuracies)
- Incremented the cv count in the GridSearchCV from 10 up to 50: The difference is only in the accuracies.
- I have tried to use PCA with k-NN to simplify: Again there was no difference on the curve.
- Tried different pre-processing techniques: I was using StandardScaler and I have changed it to MinMaxScaler, however, I could not achieve different curves (now I have slightly better accuracies though)

I do not know how to solve this problem. In the beginning, I have oversampled the dataset with SMOTE method because of the imbalance. Might this cause the problem? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You did oversample only within the training data, or otherwise did your splitting so that all copies of the same case ended up in the same subset, right?

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I oversampled only the training data, with the code piece below:
sm = SMOTE(sampling_strategy='minority', random_state=randomState)

X_train, y_train = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)